# How to tell if function being called originated from a click event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I tell if a function being called originated from a click event?

For instance, an anchor or button is clicked and the event is captured and a function is called.

Inside of this function in firebug's stack trace I can see an Object like this

```
Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=97128874, more...}
```

It says the originalEvent came from a click.

Depending on whether it came from or click or not, processing occurs differently.

Is there a way to tell if the function being called originated from a click event?

Comment: `function test(e){
    console.log(e && e.type);
}`

Comment: can you show us exactly how the function is being bound to the events?

Comment: `e.type` can Help You !

Comment: I should state the function does not take in anything except an html element. There is no event being passed in which is the problem. Changing the function definition now would require updating wherever this function is being called.

Comment: You need to show us how the function is called, if it's called when something is clicked, it's typically an event handler, unless it's some arbitrary function you call inside the event handler, then you can't access the event and have no way of knowing what event triggered the function unless you change your code to pass another argument to the function or somehing similar.

Comment: Nothing is being passed in the function. For instance the click even is handled and the function is called. No event is passed in. What I want to figure out is if the function is being called from a click event

Answer (score 5):

Any function that is triggered with an event is sent an event object. Call `.type` on this object and it will return which event it is. Here is a simple example from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/):

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  alert( event.type ); // "click"
});
```

So lets say you want to listen for both clicks and typing in a text input:

```
$( "input" ).on("click keyup", eventHandler);
```

But you want to do something special on a click:

```
eventHandler = function(event){
  if (event.type === 'click'){
    // code to execute if there is a click
  } else {
    // code to execute if there is a non-click event
  }
  // code to execute for both click and non-click events
};
```

Answer (score 4):

That would be the [**event.type**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.type)

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');

elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type)
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa63f/1/)

or in jQuery

```
$('#test').on('click paste mouseenter', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa63f/2/)

Comment: event could be undefined i guess

Comment: It could, but then it's not an event handler, as event wouldn't be undefined.

Comment: @A.Wolff if the event handler is set with `addEventHandler` or via jQuery, there'll be an event object.

Answer (score 4):

See it:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xfj6/1/)

```
$('div').click(test);

function test(e){
    if(e && e.type === 'click')
        alert('called from click!');
    else alert('NOT called from click!');
}

test();
```

Comment: @ComFreek: Did you actually edit this answer just to change the jQuery version in the demo?

Comment: @BlueSkies The previous jQuery version did not work in IE 11!

Comment: @ComFreek you mean jq 1.10.1 doesn't work on IE11? I didn't know that

Comment: @ComFreek: Huh, what happens in IE11?

Comment: @BlueSkies IE outputs an "Access denied" error in line 1513: `if ( parent && parent.frameElement )`. However, the line seems to be removed in the actual jQuery repository (tag `1.10.1`)

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/AfOxOFO/1/edit)

```
function myFn( evt ){
   console.log( evt.type );
}


$('div').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', myFn);
```